# RemoveDuplicates; selecting the copy to keep

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the RemoveDuplicates function to delete rows that have the same values in column 2-4-5-6-8 and 9, using the code shown below. The problem using this function is that it deletes the last instance. I have a column that may have some information in it, and I want to keep the row that have that information. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do that using this function.

```
        .Range("A1:M" & lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9), _
        Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking on various forums, I have come to the conclusion that I have no choice but to sort my table depending on the column with the information and then use RemoveDuplicates.

Comment: You could create your own, using a concatenated string and a dictionary with the best row to use as the item, though that's probably more effort.

Comment: Yes, and what I like about RemoveDuplicates is that its fast.

Comment: Just add the column, to the array, where there will be data in the row you want to keep. If the other rows have `no data` in the additional column they will be deleted and the row with data in the column will not be deleted.